# Include count 0 if the value is empty

Tags: mysql

The below query gives the result but what i need is :

```
city_name | total |
+-----------+-------+
| Bangalore |    13 |
| Mumbai    |    21 |
| Coimbatore|     0 |
| Madurai   |     0 |
| salem     |     0 |
| Chennai   |     4 |
| Pune      |    30 |
| Ghaziabad |     1 |
| Gurgaon   |     2 |
```

But the query gives the result :

```
+-----------+-------+
| city_name | total |
+-----------+-------+ 
| Bangalore |    13 |
| Mumbai    |    21 |
| Chennai   |     4 |
| Pune      |    30 |
| Ghaziabad |     1 |
| Gurgaon   |     2 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Query:

```
select c.city_name,count(distinct r.restaurant_id) as total from restaurants r
                                    left join je_restaurant_status jrs on r.restaurant_id = jrs.restaurant_id
                                    left join locations l on l.location_id = r.location_id
                                    left outer join cities c on c.city_id = l.city_id                                                                                              where jrs.update_date < '2014-10-01 00:00:00'                        
                                     and jrs.registered=1 and jrs.operations_closed = 0 and jrs.temporary_disabled=1                                                               group by c.city_id
```

Which function can i use to include null value from mysql . I want this query to match my other query results so that there will be no conflict while dumping it in CSV file

Comment: Perhaps use a `left join` instead of `inner join`. Is it possible for you to create a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to demonstrate?

Comment: `Having count(distinct r.restaurant_id) > 0`

Comment: used left join but same result .

Comment: Having count(distinct r.restaurant_id) > 0 still gives same result .

Comment: Can you export at least your schema so that we can reproduce? A [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.city_name,count(distinct r.restaurant_id) as total from restaurants r                                   
 inner join status jrs on r.restaurant_id = jrs.restaurant_id                                        
 inner join locations l on l.location_id = r.location_id                                          
 right join cities c on c.city_id = l.city_id                                                                             
 where jrs.update_date < '2014-10-01 00:00:00'and  
 jrs.registered=1 and jrs.operations_closed = 0                                          
 group by c.city_id;
```

Comment: Please describe what you've changed and why. Code dumps are less helpful than descriptive answers.

Comment: s/inner/right in the cities join.  That will insert nulls in the other columns for cities which don't match, which is precisely what OP wanted.

Comment: changed my query can you check?

Comment: @Torrezzzz: No, that doesn't work.  If you want to use a left join, the `cities` table must be on the left side of the join.  If you want to use a right join, the `cities` table must be on the right side.  In this case, I used a right join to avoid reordering the tables.